# Managing UIScrollView content when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard

In a tutorial the code needed to move the textField when keyboard appears is right here. However, the code does not check if the the keyboard does overlap the textField. Oddly, it works even though there is no code to check the overlapping of keyboard and textField. The scrollView moves up when keyboard overlaps with the textField and does not move when the keyboard does not overlap with the textField.

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
  }

  deinit {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(true, notification: notification)
   }

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(false, notification: notification)
}

  func adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification) {
let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
let adjustmentHeight = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) - CGRectGetHeight(navigationController!.toolbar.frame) + 20) * (show ? 1 : -1)

fgScrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustmentHeight
fgScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustmentHeight

println("\(fgScrollView.contentInset.bottom)")
  }
```

After doing some research on apple developer website I found out that apple did use some code to check if the overlapping does occur.
The code is shown below

```
// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your app might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
}
```

Please explain why does the example code doesn't need to do the checking?

Comment: You might want to check this library https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: I am not expert in swift but its look like they add some delta (hightOfKeybord) and then scroll to it. In any case why not to try debug the views in Xcode.